# Creating and Object adding Member Procedure and Function - ORACLE-

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I have an interesting question in my advanced database class that is giving me some trouble.

The first step is to create an object which I have done and is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EmployeeObj AS OBJECT
(
    EmployeeID      NUMBER,
    LastName        VARCHAR2(100),
    FirstName       VARCHAR2(100),
    AddressLine1    VARCHAR2(100),
    AddressLine2    VARCHAR2(100),
    City            VARCHAR2(100),
    State           VARCHAR2(100),
    Zip             VARCHAR2(10),
    StartDate       DATE,
    EndDate         DATE,
    JobTitle        VARCHAR2(100),
    MEMBER PROCEDURE Display, 
    MEMBER FUNCTION DaysOnJob RETURN NUMBER
);
```

Next it asks to create a member procedure that displays all the fields. Then it asks to create a member function that displays the number of days since the beginning of the job using SYSDATE. I think I did this properly and it is shown below:

```
CREATE TYPE BODY EmployeeObj AS

    MEMBER PROCEDURE Display IS
        BEGIN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EmployeeID: ' || EmployeeID);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name: ' || FirstName ||', '|| LastName);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Address: ' || AddressLine1 || ', ' ||  AddressLine2 || ' ' || City || ', '|| State || ' '|| Zip);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Start Date: ' || StartDate);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EndDate: ' || EndDate);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job Title: ' || JobTitle);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Days On Job: ');
        END Display;

     MEMBER FUNCTION DaysOnJob RETURN NUMBER IS 
        BEGIN
            IF EndDate = 'NULL' THEN
                RETURN SYSDATE - StartDate;           
                    ELSE IF EndDate != 'NULL' THEN
                        RETURN EndDate - StartDate; 
                    END IF;
            END IF;
        END DaysOnJob;

END;
/
```

Finally it asks me to create an instance of the object I created and call the DISPLAY member procedure to output the instance to the screen. This is where I have trouble. When I run this code:

```
DECLARE 
    --This is null initially--
    myEmployee EmployeeObj;
BEGIN
    --building the object--
    myEmployee := EmployeeObj(1234, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '1234', '01-JAN-98', '01-JUL-18', 'Software Engineer');
    myEmployee.Display;

END;
/
```

Everything works fine, but if I try to call the DaysOnJob function from within the procedure, I get all kinds of errors?

Does anyone know how to properly call the member function from within the procedure so that I can output the number of days on the job as part of my Display procedure for the object?

Any help would be appreciated. Below is my implementation and error message I receive.

```
CREATE TYPE BODY EmployeeObj AS

    MEMBER PROCEDURE Display IS
        BEGIN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EmployeeID: ' || EmployeeID);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name: ' || FirstName ||', '|| LastName);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Address: ' || AddressLine1 || ', ' ||  AddressLine2 || ' ' || City || ', '|| State || ' '|| Zip);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Start Date: ' || StartDate);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EndDate: ' || EndDate);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job Title: ' || JobTitle);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Days On Job:' || DaysOnJob);
        END Display;

     MEMBER FUNCTION DaysOnJob RETURN NUMBER  IS
        BEGIN
            IF EndDate IS NULL THEN
                RETURN SYSDATE - StartDate;           
                    ELSE IF EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN
                        RETURN EndDate - StartDate; 
                    END IF;
            END IF;
        END DaysOnJob;

END;
/
 --4. Creating Instance of EmployeeObj--
DECLARE 
    --This is null initially--
    myEmployee EmployeeObj;

BEGIN
    --building the object--
    myEmployee := EmployeeObj(1234, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, date '2018-01-01', date '2018-07-01', 'Software Engineer');
    myEmployee.Display;


END;
/
```

ERRORS ARE BELOW

```
DECLARE 
    --This is null initially--
    myEmployee EmployeeObj;

BEGIN
    --building the object--
    myEmployee := EmployeeObj(1234, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, date '2018-01-01', date '2018-07-01', 'Software Engineer');
    myEmployee.Display;


END;
Error report -
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at "MILLERJL6.EMPLOYEEOBJ", line 16
ORA-06512: at "MILLERJL6.EMPLOYEEOBJ", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 8
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.
```

Comment: How are you trying to call the function and what errors do you get?

Comment: I am trying to call the function inside of the member procedure statement so that it would output the information as a calculation just like the rest of the information from the Employee object. So after Job Title:  the next line would be DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Days On Job:' || DaysOnJob); IDEALLY. A requirement of the question is that member procedure should call the function to display the days since start date

Comment: OK, so the problem isn't actually with the call, it's just revealing an error in the function - probably what Aleksej already spotted? Including the call and the complete error stack you get in your question would really help as it would pinpoint the error (instead of us trying to guess what is happening).

Comment: I added the error report and the way I was trying to do it to the post.

Comment: That error from your original code is exactly what Aleksej pointed out. Line 16 is the invalid  `= 'NULL'` check. I'm not sure why you've added the fixed code to your question, that is confusing and won't get the error you showed?

Comment: Maybe you tryed to rebuild the type body exactly as is, but you would need create OR REPLACE in that case; otherwise, the body remains as you created it the first time, with the wrong null check. Please try to rebuild the type body with create or replace and let us know

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing dates with strings to check `null`; if you want to check whether a value is null or not, `is [not] null` is the right way:

```
MEMBER FUNCTION DaysOnJob RETURN NUMBER IS 
BEGIN
    IF EndDate is null THEN
        RETURN SYSDATE - StartDate;           
            ELSE IF EndDate is not null THEN
                RETURN EndDate - StartDate; 
            END IF;
    END IF;
END DaysOnJob;
```

Or

```
MEMBER FUNCTION DaysOnJob RETURN NUMBER IS 
BEGIN
    IF EndDate is null THEN
        RETURN SYSDATE - StartDate;           
    ELSE 
        RETURN EndDate - StartDate; 
    END IF;
END DaysOnJob;
```

or even

```
MEMBER FUNCTION DaysOnJob RETURN NUMBER IS 
BEGIN
    RETURN nvl(EndDate, sysdate) - StartDate; 
END DaysOnJob;
```

Also, better use the ANSI date format, more than relying on NLS settings:

```
myEmployee := EmployeeObj( ... , date '2018-01-01', date '2018-07-01', ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

A function returns a value, so you need to asign that to a variable:

```
DECLARE 
    myEmployee EmployeeObj;
    days number;
BEGIN
    myEmployee := EmployeeObj(1234, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL',
        'NULL', 'NULL', '1234', date '1998-01-01', date '2018-07-01',
        'Software Engineer');
    myEmployee.Display;
    days := myEmployee.daysOnJob;
    dbms_output.putline(days):
END;
/
```

or can use it directly:

```
    dbms_output.put_line(myEmployee.daysOnJob);
```

or prefixed with text - this ispresumably what you need inside your procedure:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Days On Job: ' || daysOnJob);
```

You should pass dates into the constructor, not strings; either with date literals as I have done, or via `to_date()`. Don't rely on implicit conversion or NLS settings.

I'm almost certain you want to be passing in `null` (without quotes) rather than the literal string `'NULL'` for the other arguments, but that isn't entirely clear.

You also shouldn't rely on `dbms_output` as the caller cay not have that enabled, but that seems to be part of the assignment.